# Minimal AccessString needed to give a Redis user read permission on all Nodes in all shards

Tags: redis, acl, stackexchange.redis, amazon-elasticache

I have a setup with 3 shards, each shard has one master and two replicas. I want to a have a master user and multiple read users.
 The problem is that I can’t figure out a way to only give the users read access.
The only access string that works is this: `on ~* +@all`.

What I have tried:

1.
`on ~* -@all +@read`

error: You miss Echo command

2.
`on ~* -@all +@read +@connection`

Error:
Endpoint Unspecified/[Hidden]-0001-001.[Hidden].com:6379 serving hashslot 814 is not reachable at this point of time. Please check connectTimeout value. If it is low, try increasing it to give the ConnectionMultiplexer a chance to recover from the network disconnect. IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=10,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=1,Free=32766,Min=10,Max=32767).

3.
`on ~* +@all -@dangerous`

error: same as 2.

The only thing that works for me is `on ~* +@all`. I have tried reading the documentation, but I can´t see what I`am missing?

Could there be an issue in the Redis client(?):

```
 public class RedisCacheClient : ICacheClient
    {
        private readonly Lazy<IConnectionMultiplexer> _Connection;
        private IConnectionMultiplexer Connection => _Connection.Value;
        private IDatabase Database => Connection.GetDatabase();

        public RedisCacheClient(RedisConnectionSettings redisConnectionSettings)
        {
            _Connection = new Lazy<IConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
            {
                ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect($"{redisConnectionSettings.Url}:{redisConnectionSettings.Port}", options =>
                {
                    options.ClientName = redisConnectionSettings.ClientName ?? redisConnectionSettings.Username;
                    options.Ssl = redisConnectionSettings.Ssl;
                    options.Password = redisConnectionSettings.Password;
                    options.User = redisConnectionSettings.Username;
                    options.AbortOnConnectFail = false;
                    options.ReconnectRetryPolicy = new ExponentialRetry(5000);
                });
                return redis;
            });
        }

        public async Task<string?> GetAsync(RedisKey key)
        {
            return await Database.StringGetAsync(key, CommandFlags.PreferReplica).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAsync(IEnumerable<RedisKey> keys)
        {
            RedisValue[] stringGetAsync = await Database.StringGetAsync(keys.ToArray(), CommandFlags.PreferReplica).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return stringGetAsync.Where(x => x.HasValue).Select(x => (string)x);
        }
    }
```

- Using AWS elastic cache
- Rediss engine: 6.x
- NET 6
- using stackexchange.redis

thanks

Comment: Not sure how you're doing it. 
Elasticache redis blocks adding of new users as ACL command is restricted.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/RestrictedCommands.html

Comment: We use the AWS cli to create users: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Clusters.RBAC.html#Users-management